# Shiny future() : Error in ctx$onInvalidate: Reactive context was created in one process and accessed from another

Tags: r, asynchronous, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the below server code which is giving the error when future() is used while it works without future/promises. This has stuck me for longtime and could not figure out the source of error.  The reactive values  `qt_files$file1`, `qt_files$file2` and `ile_ped$ped` are called in both the future() functions. Could this be the source of error?

> Error in ctx$onInvalidate: Reactive context was created in one process and accessed from another

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {   
dom_content <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(input$dom_run, { 
prog <- Progress$new(session) 
prog$set(message = "Analysis in progress", 
         detail = "This may take a while...", 
         value = NULL) 

qt_files <- gqt_list()  ###calling reactive values to be used in future
ile_ped <-   ed_file() 

future({
system("cat qt_files$file1 ile_ped$ped") 
system("cat qt_files$file2 ile_ped$ped")      
###the two system commands give the output "dom.gz" which is returned to R

dom_vcf <- vcfR::read.vcfR("dom.gz") 
dom_out <- cbind(vcfR::getFIX(dom_vcf,getINFO = TRUE), dom_vcf@gt) 
dom_out 
}) %...>% 
dom_content() %>%
finally(~prog$close()) 
return(NULL)
})

observeEvent(dom_content(), {
updateTabsetPanel(session, "dom_tab", "dom_results")
output$dom_table <-
  DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(
    req(dom_content())
  ))
output$dom_summary <- renderText(paste("Total filtered:",nrow(dom_content())))
})




rec_content <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(input$rec_run, { 
prog <- Progress$new(session) 
prog$set(message = "Analysis in progress", 
         detail = "This may take a while...", 
         value = NULL) 

qt_files <- gqt_list()  ###calling reactive values to be used in future
ile_ped <-   ed_file() 

future({
system("cat qt_files$file1 ile_ped$ped") 
system("cat qt_files$file2 ile_ped$ped")      
###the two system commands give the output "rec.gz" which is returned to R

rec_vcf <- vcfR::read.vcfR("rec.gz") 
rec_out <- cbind(vcfR::getFIX(rec_vcf,getINFO = TRUE), rec_vcf@gt) 
rec_out 
}) %...>% 
rec_content() %>%
finally(~prog$close()) 
return(NULL)
})

observeEvent(rec_content(), {
updateTabsetPanel(session, "rec_tab", "rec_results")
output$rec_table <-
  DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(
    req(rec_content())
  ))
output$rec_summary <- renderText(paste("Total filtered:",nrow(rec_content())))
  })
```

Comment: I found that using `plan(multiprocess)` gives this error. When the app is run without this line and restarting R it works. Im currently working on a Mac with 4 cores. Could someone throw some light on how to interpret this.

Comment: I don't understand what `system("cat qt_files$file1 ile_ped$ped")` is supposed to do. `cat` is a **system/shell command**, whereas `qt_files$file1` and `ile_ped$ped` is **R code** - that does not look correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive values can't be read or set from a different process with futures. Check out these sections in the `promises` documentation:

- [Shiny-specific caveats and limitations](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html#shiny-specific-caveats-and-limitations)
- [Observers](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html#observers) (see the note at the bottom of the async example)

Here's an example of the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)

server <- function(input, output) {
  counter <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$incrementBtn, {
    currentCount <- counter()
    future({
      counter(currentCount + 1)  # errors
    })
  })

  output$result <- renderText({
    counter()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("incrementBtn", "Increment"),
  verbatimTextOutput("result")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To work around this, you can return the result from the future and set the reactive value in the promise handler instead (which runs in the main process). Something like:

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)

server <- function(input, output) {
  counter <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$incrementBtn, {
    currentCount <- counter()
    f <- future({
      currentCount + 1
    })

    f %...>% counter()
  })

  output$result <- renderText({
    counter()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("incrementBtn", "Increment"),
  verbatimTextOutput("result")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: after reading your sample code and the observers documentation link, i have updated the code in OP as per these references. However,  i still get the same error. I feel like i am missing on a small thing which makes the problem complex..

Comment: It looks fine to me. Is there anywhere else in the app where reactive values are used in futures? Or is it possible to strip the app down to a runnable example? Unfortunately there's no stack trace to look at so it's hard to tell where this is happening.

Comment: Yes, there are different reactive values in different futures. I have added one more block of the app with another reactive value starting from `rec_content` in the code, if this could give a hint.

Comment: I have updated the OP. Briefly, the reactive values  `qt_files$file1`, `qt_files$file2` and `ile_ped$ped` are called in both the future() . Does this give any hint?

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see an issue in this snippet. Could you try to create or extract out a runnable example?

Comment: Well my guess is correct. I have changed the variable names to which the reactive values are assigned that are used in each future system()  command and it worked.

Comment: Thanks Greg. The issue is addressed in the caveats link posted. I figured it out late. I am exactly calling r1 in r2 without assigning r1 to a value as described in the shiny-specific caveats and Limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the reactive values used in system() commands are called within future and reactive values and reactive expressions cannot be read from within a future.

Here is the [shiny-specific Caveats and Limitations](https://Shiny-specific%20caveats%20and%20limitations) explantion under "Shiny-specific Caveats and Limitations". I hope this helps someone.